# Issues accessing json data using AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, json

I've just started learning angularJS and am trying to figure out why the following code doesn't work

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Angular JS Ajax</title>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div ng-app="mainApp" ng-controller="studentController">
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <th>Name</th>

                    <th>Roll No</th>

                    <th>Percentage</th>
                </tr>

                <tr ng-repeat="student in students">
                    <td>{{ student.Name }}</td>

                    <td>{{student.RollNo}}</td>

                    <td>{{student.Percentage}}</td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>

        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.15/angular.min.js"></script>

        <script>
            var mainApp = angular.module("mainApp");

            mainApp.controller("studentController", function($scope,$http){

                var url = "data.txt";

                $http.get(url).success(function(response){
                    $scope.students = response;
                });
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

When I change the attribute of `ng-app` to `""` (instead of `"mainApp"'), and replace the`` code above with the following, the application works.
I'd really appreciate if anyone could explain to me why this is the case.

```
    <script>
        function studentController($scope, $http){
            var url = "data.txt";

            $http.get(url).success(function(response){
                $scope.students = response;
            });
        };
    </script>
```

Here's the data.txt file:

```
[
    {
        "Name": "Mahesh Parashar",
        "RollNo": 101,
        "Percentage": "80%"
    },

    {
        "Name": "Dinkar Kad",
        "RollNo": 191,
        "Percentage": "75%"
    }
]
```

Thank you!

Comment: what error you see in console?

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to add [] with app module declaration

```
var mainApp = angular.module("mainApp",[]);
```

Comment: Hi Paresh,

Do you mind explaining to me the point of having the `[]` brackets, and whether they ever contain anything or should be empty in all cases? Thank you!

Comment: No it not empty always, you need to add depencies like ngMap, ngSenitize  etc

Answer (score 1):

The first one is not working because you don't supply the right syntax for `mainApp`. You need to add `[]` for module declaration. 
This should look like below:

```
var mainApp = angular.module('mainApp', []);
    mainApp.controller('studentController', function($scope, $timeout) {
      var url = "data.txt";

      $http.get(url).success(function(response) {
          $scope.students = response;
      });
 });
```

The second one is working fine simply because you don't have any app module declaration.

Comment: Ahhh, I complete forgot about the `[]`.
Do you mind explaining why we need the `[]` in the syntax, and do these brackets ever contain anything in some cases? Thanks!

Comment: The bracket means injecting dependencies like `'ngAnimate', 'ngAria',  'ngCookies', 'ngResource',` and etc depends on your project.

Answer (score 0):

You need to Parse it to json object
Please try JSON.parse.

jsonObj = JSON.parse(response);

Hope this will help you